# Как правильно показать форму

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как правильно показать нужную форму с помощью Jquery. К примеру нажимаем на "Зарегистрироваться" и показываем нужную форму.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdXvWJ)

```js
$('.login-container a').click(function() {
  var targetclass = $(this).data("targetclass");
  $('form.' + targetclass).animate({
    height: "toggle",
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, "slow");
})
```

```css
.login {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.login-header,
.login p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.login-triangle {
  width: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #3a4049;
}

.login-header {
  background: #3a4049;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.login-container {
  background: #ebebeb;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.login p {
  padding: 12px;
}

.login input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 16px;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.95em;
}

.login input[type="email"],
.login input[type="password"] {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #bbb;
  color: #555;
}

.login input[type="email"]:focus,
.login input[type="password"]:focus {
  border-color: #888;
}

.login input[type="submit"] {
  background: #3a4049;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #17c;
}

.login input[type="submit"]:focus {
  border-color: #05a;
}

.login-container a {
  color: #3a4049;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 24px;
}

.login-container a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.login-container:nth-child(4),
.login-container:nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login">
  <div class="login-triangle"></div>
  <h2 class="login-header">Тестовая форма</h2>
  <form class="login-container form-auth">
    <p><input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email" autofocus required></p>
    <p><input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" required></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Войти"></p>
    <span>
   <a data-targetclass="form-respass" href="#">Забыли пароль?</a>
   <a data-targetclass="form-reg" href="#">Зарегистрироваться</a>
  </span>
  </form>
  <form class="login-container form-respass">
    <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите email" autofocus></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
    <span>
   <a data-targetclass="form-auth" href="#">Войти</a>
   <a data-targetclass="form-reg" href="#">Зарегистрироваться</a>
  </span>
  </form>
  <form class="login-container form-reg">
    <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autofocus required></p>
    <p><input type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" required>
      <p><input type="password" placeholder="Подтвердите пароль" required>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться"></p>
        <span>
   <a data-targetclass="form-auth" href="#">Войти</a>
   <a data-targetclass="form-respass" href="#">Забыли пароль?</a>
  </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присвойте формам индивидуальные `id`/классы, которые также укажите в `data-target` атрибутах анкер-тэгов.

```
<form class="login-container form-register" ...
...
<a data-targetclass="form-register" ...

$('.login-container a').click(function(){
  var targetClass = $(this).data("targetclass");
  $('form.' + targetClass).animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```